# nested \ifnum commands

Tags: macros, tex-core

I'm trying to make macro to work in biblatex `edition` field.
Logic is following:

- if edition =1 there is suffix -li (1-li)
- if edition>1 and if edition<21 there is prefix me- (me-15,me-20 ..etc)
- if edition = 40,60,80,100,200,...1000 there is also prefix me-
- in other cases suffix -e (31-e, 21-e, 129-e, 1010-e)

here is a code which works:

```
 \protected\def\mkbibmascord#1{%
 \ifnum #1=1 #1-li \else %
 \ifnum #1<21 %
\ifnum #1>1 me-#1 \fi \else %
\ifnum #1 = 40  me-#1 \else%
\ifnum #1 = 60  me-#1 \else%
\ifnum #1 = 80  me-#1 \else%
\ifnum #1 = 100 me-#1 \else %
\ifnum #1 = 200  me-#1 \else %
#1-e
\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi\fi%
}%
\protected\def\mkbibordinal{\mkbibmascord}%
\protected\def\mkbibfemord{\mkbibmascord}%
\protected\def\mkbibneutord{\mkbibmascord}%
```

but how can i write general code/improve above code?  (not only for 200), becouse let say for calendar there will be alot if/fi-s

Comment: There might be some streamlining, if all the possible cases possessed consecutive numbers.  But since they do not, nested `\ifnum` branching is probably the best you can do.

Comment: you are right , but shortening a code can be possible something like `break`, `and`,`==' (equality) commands or `case`(like \case{n}) switch :) .. Isearch 'math in tex' but search gives just how to write mathequations, not TeX aritmetic :)...I need to learn more :)

Comment: Are these ordinal numbers? In which language? Is there a reference for the rules?

Comment: yes. Language is georgian.. here are examples..no general rule is given in English http://learn101.org/georgian_numbers.php http://mylanguages.org/georgian_numbers.php .. Actually i run little bit forward..I'm going to write Gregoriancalendar-to-Ald Georgian calendar transliator and will need TeX arithmetic a lot.

Comment: Can remove ifnum #1 >1  in above code...works also fine `\ifnum #1<21 %
 me-#1  \else %`

Comment: I also checked how it is made for english...I need to count houndreds..did not make it and wrote what is above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an implementation in `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Nn \georgian_ordinal:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { 1 < #1 < 21 }
   { me\mbox{-}#1 }
   { \georgian_ordinal_aux:n { #1 } }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \georgian_ordinal_aux:n
 {
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {    1 }{ #1\mbox{-}li }
    {   40 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {   60 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {   80 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  100 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  200 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  300 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  400 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  500 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  600 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  700 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  800 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    {  900 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
    { 1000 }{ me\mbox{-}#1 }
  }
  { #1\mbox{-}e }
 }

\cs_set_eq:NN \mkbibmascord  \georgian_ordinal:n
\cs_set_eq:NN \mkbibordinal  \georgian_ordinal:n
\cs_set_eq:NN \mkbibfemord   \georgian_ordinal:n
\cs_set_eq:NN \mkbibneutcord \georgian_ordinal:n

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

% a loop for testing
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nnnn { 1 } { 1 } { 1010 } { \mkbibmascord { #1 } ~ }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

I only show the test between 1 and 210:

[image]

Maybe something more efficient can be done if the rules for numbers above 1000 are explained.

Comment: Nice.. I like that for loop in expl3, but will need to learn that language :)

Comment: Why the `\mbox`es? In that case, you should use `\cs_new_protected:Npn`.

Comment: @Manuel They are to avoid line breaks; actually `\mbox` is sufficiently robust for being in an expandable command.

Comment: @egreg But the rule in expl3 was to define as `protected` everything that contains non-expandable tokens. Good to know about linebreaks.

Answer (score 4):

The solution using `\ifnum`s and using `\variants{num}{list}{true-text}{false-text}` macro which expands to the "true-text" if num is equal to the number in the list else it expands to the "false-text".

```
\def\variants#1#2{\variantsA{#1}#2,,\end}
\def\variantsA#1#2,{\ifx,#2,\expandafter\variantsE \else
   \ifnum#1=#2 \variantsC \else
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\variantsA
   \fi\fi{#1}}
\def\variantsC#1\end#2#3{\fi\fi#2}
\def\variantsE#1\end#2#3{#3}

\protected\def\mkbibmascord#1{%
   \ifnum#1<1 #1-e\else
   \ifnum#1=1 #1-li\else
   \ifnum#1<21 me-#1\else
   \variants{#1}{40,60,80,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000}{me-#1}{#1-e}%
   \fi\fi\fi
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The question has two relatively independent aspects:

```
 1. how to organize gracefully a long list of `\ifnum..` clauses, 
 2. how to automatize over a list.
```

I won't delve much about the second part here, illustrated in the code below by the handling of `300, 400, .., 1000` via `\xintApplyUnbraced` from package `xinttools`. This is expandable. And the Test itself uses an `\xintFor` loop (non-expandable). For example `wipet's answer` has one-line macros sufficient here. By laziness I used the loops from `xinttools`.

My answer is mainly the observation that very simple macros:

```
\long\def\DoThis #1#2\OrThat #3{\fi #1}
\long\def\OrThat #1{#1}
```

can be used to handle point 1. No more `\fi\fi\fi\fi...\fi`. And expandability is maintained.

```
\long\def\DoThis #1#2\OrThat #3{\fi #1}
\long\def\OrThat #1{#1}

% for the (optional) list manipulations in the code and in the Test
\input xinttools.sty

% Notice that this \georgianordinal is an expandable macro
\def\georgianordinal #1{%
   \ifnum #1=1  \DoThis{1-li}\fi
   \ifnum #1<21 \DoThis{me-#1}\fi
   \ifnum #1=40 \DoThis{me-#1}\fi
   \ifnum #1=60 \DoThis{me-#1}\fi
   \ifnum #1=80 \DoThis{me-#1}\fi
   \ifnum #1=100 \DoThis{me-#1}\fi
   \ifnum #1=200 \DoThis{me-#1}\fi
   \xintApplyUnbraced
        {\georgianordinalaux {#1}}
        {{300}{400}{500}{600}{700}{800}{900}{1000}}%
   \OrThat {#1-e}%
}

% notice the space before \ifnum, which is there to stop 
% an expansion done via \romannumeral-`0 by \xintApplyUnbraced
\def\georgianordinalaux #1#2{ \ifnum #1=#2 \DoThis{me-#1}\fi}

% Test:

\xintFor #1 in {\xintintegers} \do {%
     \georgianordinal {\the#1},
     \ifnum#1>1050 \expandafter\xintBreakFor\fi
}

\bye
```

[image]