# How to check if a macro expands to one of several strings?

Tags: conditionals, etoolbox

I have the following problem: I am using the `etoolbox` package to check if a macro (say, `\foo`) expands to one of several possible strings (say, `bar`, `baz`, `abc`, or other). I need to execute different code depending on what string `\foo` expands to.

My current solution is

```
\ifdefstring{\foo}{bar}
{% if \foo is bar
  <do something>
}
{% if \foo is not bar
  \ifdefstring{\foo}{baz}
  {% if \foo is baz
    <do something else>
  }
  {% if \foo is not bar or baz
    \ifdefstring{\foo}{abc}
    {% if \foo is abc
      <do something else>
    }
    {% if \foo is not bar, baz, or abc
      <do something else>
    }
  }
}
```

Although this works, it is not satisfactory due to the deep nesting, and it doesn't generalize well to longer lists of possible strings. In my real situation, I have up to eight possible strings to check, so this solution creates unreadable code.

My question is, what alternative options (in LaTeX2e) do I have to check if a macro expands to one of several strings?

Ideally, the solution would also work for other `etoolbox` comparison commands (e.g., `\ifstrequal`). However, the solution need not use the `etoolbox` package.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29133/32374 help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `\foo` expands to a simple string, which survives a `\csname`, the following method can be used, which does not need LaTeX3:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\@namedef{foo@bar}{%
  \typeout{\noexpand\foo is bar}%
  % <do something>
}
\@namedef{foo@baz}{%
  \typeout{\noexpand\foo is baz}%
  % <do something>
}
\@namedef{foo@abc}{%
  \typeout{\noexpand\foo is abc}%
  % <do someting>
}

\newcommand*{\evaluate@foo}{%
  \@ifundefined{foo@\foo}{%
    \errmessage{\noexpand\foo has unknown value}%
  }{%
    \@nameuse{foo@\foo}%
  }%
}
\providecommand*{\foo}{}% initialization

% Test

\def\foo{baz}
\evaluate@foo

\def\foo{abc}
\evaluate@foo

\def\foo{xyz}
\evaluate@foo

\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
\foo is baz
\foo is abc
! \foo has unknown value.
```

Comment: This looks like it might do the trick! I'll try it out later today and accept your answer if it does. Thanks!

Comment: This idea ended up working perfectly, thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

The best solution I can think of is `expl3`’s `\str_case:nnTF`.  Here I generate a variant to take one token instead of a test string and compares to expansion of that token to the list.  If no match is found in the list an appropriate message is output.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { VnF }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \artem_testfoo:N #1
 {
  \texttt{ \cs_to_str:N #1 } ~ 
  \str_case:VnF #1
   {
    { bar } { is ~ bar }
    { baz } { is ~ baz }
    { abc } { is ~ abc }
   }
   { is ~ neither ~ bar, ~ nor ~ baz, ~ nor ~ abc. }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \testfoo { m }
 {
  \artem_testfoo:N #1
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\def\foo{bar}
\testfoo\foo

\def\foo{baz}
\testfoo\foo

\def\foo{abc}
\testfoo\foo

\def\foo{xyz}
\testfoo\foo

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: BTW: `\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_case:nnF { V }` would suffice :)

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer! Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with LaTeX3 at all (I should have specified that in the question).

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy with `xparse` and `expl3`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifstring}{mO{}m}
 {
  \str_case:onF { #1 } { #3 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\foo}{abc}

\xifstring{\foo}[No match]
 {
  {abc}{String is `abc'}
  {def}{String is `def'}
  {ghi}{String is `ghi'}
 }

\renewcommand{\foo}{def}

\xifstring{\foo}[No match]
 {
  {abc}{String is `abc'}
  {def}{String is `def'}
  {ghi}{String is `ghi'}
 }

\renewcommand{\foo}{ghi}

\xifstring{\foo}[No match]
 {
  {abc}{String is `abc'}
  {def}{String is `def'}
  {ghi}{String is `ghi'}
 }

\renewcommand{\foo}{foo}

\xifstring{\foo}[No match]
 {
  {abc}{String is `abc'}
  {def}{String is `def'}
  {ghi}{String is `ghi'}
 }

\end{document}
```

The optional argument is for what you want when there's no match (default value, do nothing).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer! Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with LaTeX3 at all (I should have specified that in the question).

Comment: Why do you need to be familiar with latex3? Just think of it as a package that you load that provides programming tools.

Answer (score 3):

The simple minded method from my [other answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/266544/4686) avoids nesting. Here we don't have `TeX` like `\if..\fi` but suitable wrappers, so we need to modify a bit the definitions.

```
\long\def\DoThis #1#2\OrThat #3{#1}
\long\def\OrThat #1{#1}% \@firstofone

\ifdefstring{\foo}{bar}{\DoThis{do something}}{}%
\ifdefstring{\foo}{baz}{\DoThis{do something else}}{}%
\ifdefstring{\foo}{bat}{\DoThis{do something different}}{}%
\OrThat {in case all tests fail}%
```

Remark: once a test is positive all successive ones are skipped, due to the definition of `\DoThis` macro.

Comment: the method applies to all possible branching conditional of the type `\ifsometest{..}...{YES}{NO}` .