# How to expand macro containing another macro

Tags: expansion, csname

Assume a situation that I have predefined some macros like `\abc`, `\aotherc`, ... etc. The macro is just like `\a#1c`, and `#1` is defined by `\x`.

In other words, I don't know which of `\abc`, `\aotherc`, ... to be used, but all these macros have been defined. then how can I write `\a\xc` with `\x` expanded first, and then the whole macro expands to the correct content?

It is my naming convention that causes this problem. Adjusting the order of the subnames just fix it. But I wonder if there is a way to solve this.

```
\def\abc{abc}
\def\aotherc{aotherc}
\def\x{b}
```

My attemp

```
\expandafter\a\csname \x\endcsname c
```

The first comment is right. Write like this

```
\csname a\x c\endcsname
```

then it will expand correctly.
My last run came with other problem.

Comment: Use `\csname a\x c\endcsname`.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/464656/197451

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Looking forward to seeing `tabularz`.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck I think you were using `\csname a\x c\endcsname` a lot in your package already. So maybe you can explain a bit more the context.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat it is my naming convention that causes the macro which is to be expanded surrouding by another one. Adjust the order of the subname can fix this problem, but I wonder if there is a way to solve this.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why @PaulGaborit does not work for you. (I still do not fully understand the question.)

Comment: the code in the first comment is the answer isn't it? I do not understand your comment about the name convention, nor do I understand the edit what space "can not be removed" Please do not post disconnected fragments, post a small complete plain tex test file, and say what output you expected.

Comment: What space "cannot be removed"?

Comment: I am sorry about that. It was my fault. The first comment is right. Sorry for confusing you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

is the output from the plain TeX file:

```
\def\abc{abc}
\def\aotherc{aotherc}



1:
\def\x{b}
\csname a\x c\endcsname

2:
\def\x{other}
\csname a\x c\endcsname

\bye
```

Which shows that in each case, first `\x` was expanded to construct the csnames `\abc` (in the first case) or `\aotherc` (in the second) and then that constructed csname was expanded to produce the appropriate text.

Comment: You can add a third case: `\def\x\{foo}\csname a\x\c\endcsname` with no result... and no error (like `! Undefined control sequence.`).