# A macro to check command expandability

Tags: macros, expl3, expansion, programming, error-writing

I would like to create **a command that checks whether an expression is fully expandable, and crashes if not** (ideally printing an error message). I would like to do that **without a specific TeX engine in mind**. I think it's related to this question [Check if macro is fully expandable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/464646/check-if-macro-is-fully-expandable), but the provided answer requires LuaTeX.

---

**Test code**

A test code would look like this:

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\checkexpandability}{m}{
    % CODE HERE
}

\newcommand{\expandable}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\notexpandable}[1]{%
    \edef\myvariable{\expandable{#1}}%
    \myvariable%
}

\begin{document}
\checkexpandability{\expandable{test}} % Should be OK
\checkexpandability{\notexpandable{test}} % Should CRASH
\checkexpandability{\IfBeginWith{string}{str}{true}{false}} % Should CRASH
\end{document}
```

---

**In case it's too complicated**

If it's not doable, then I am ok to modify the command signature to include a parameter that is what the command should expand to:

```
\begin{document}
\checkexpandability{\expandable{test}}{test} % Should be OK
\checkexpandability{\notexpandable{test}}{test} % Should CRASH
\checkexpandability{\IfBeginWith{string}{str}{true}{false}}{true} % Should CRASH
\end{document}
```

---

**Comment on expandability**

Since the definition of fully expandable is not as clear as one could think (see comment below), the context of this question is that I'm just trying to create something that helps me debug some code. I'm ok to restrain the question to this specific behavior : whether the macro would work in the context macros like the `\color` command:

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\expandable}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\notexpandable}[1]{%
    \edef\myvariable{\expandable{#1}}%
    \myvariable%
}
    
\begin{document}
\color{\expandable{blue}} % OK
\color{\notexpandable{red}} % CRASHES
X
\end{document}
```

Basically, the `\color` command does the kind of job I'm looking for, it's just that I would like to call it `\checkexpandability`, be a little more generic, and print a nice error message.

Comment: it is rather unclear what you mean by expandable. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66168/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I added a comment at the end of the question

Comment: what you want to do is not really possible, also you need to define what you mean by "expandable"  `\relax` for example is safe in an `\edef` but not in `\color`. If you mean a command that expands to something legal in the current context, then there is no general definition.

Comment: there is no context "like" the `\color` command, only _the_ color command. The argument of `\color`  has to expand to a valid color name otherwise you get an error. There is no sense in which it "checks for expandability" it just expects a color name (after expansion)

Comment: `\color{\expandable{123}} ` would error too.

Comment: It would be possible to have a non-expandable test to query if something only works by expansion, based on the `unravel` code. But that is not a practical approach if you are wanting to use this in a document. I suspect there is some wider context ... which is not at all clear.

Comment: How to handle expandable "expressions" like `\infiniteloop{a}` where `\infinteloop` is defined as `\def\infiniteloop#1{\infiniteloop{#1}}` or  as `\def\infiniteloop#1{\infiniteloop{#1}#1}`? (The latter definition might yield `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=...].`)

Comment: And the primitive `\input` (which is renamed to `\@@input` in LaTeX 2e) is expandable as well...

Comment: And how to handle expansion-scenarios where `\outer`-tokens play a rôle, like the expression `\macro{0}` with `\def\macro#1{#1 1 2 3 \willbeouter}\outer\def\willbeouter {4 5 6}`? At some stage of expansion you get the outer token `\willbeouter`. Examining this by expandable methods only won't be that trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the basic misunderstanding is

> Basically, the `\color` command does the kind of job I'm looking for,

The `\color` command does no checks of the type requested, it simply expects that after expansion the argument is a defined color name. If the expansion fails you get a low level error or if it expands to an undefined color you get a specific error message, but no part of the processing is generic or applies to a command other than commands expecting colors.

The one version that could be implemented is the version with an expected expansion as that is simply asking if the two arguments are equal after expansion. The L3 programming layer has several variants of that or you could use the `ifthen` package and

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\expandable{test}}{test}}{yes}{no}
```

which will return yes if the arguments expand to the same thing, no if they do not, or give a low level error if the argument is not safe in an expansion context (which is what is usually meant by "is not expandable")

Answer (score 3):

To debug your code, I'd just use `\typeout`.

```
\documentclass[preview = true, varwidth = true]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\expandable}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\notexpandable}[1]{%
    \edef\myvariable{\expandable{#1}}%
    \myvariable%
}
    
\begin{document}
\typeout{\expandable{blue}} % OK, print "blue"
\typeout{\notexpandable{red}} % CRASHES
X
\end{document}
```

The point is that `\typeout` will fully expand its argument, then print whatever the fully expanded result is on the terminal --- so you can just take a look at the terminal.

For the first case it prints `blue`, so everything is fine. For the second case, it crashes.

---

Of course, there are two problems with the approach above.

- Even if `\expandable{blue}` **is** fully expandable (whatever it means), **it may not be the case that `\color` is guaranteed to fully expand its argument before interpreting the result as a color**. (I guess by [Hyrum's law](https://www.hyrumslaw.com/) it would practically be to avoid breaking "existing packages", however.)

  So, if you want to be extra sure, it's better to expand it in advance using e.g. [`\ExpandArgs`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/133779/250119).
- The information on category code, as well as any special character lurking in the code (e.g. space versus tab), is lost.

  In practice this wouldn't matter much, but sometimes it does. (e.g. when you try to debug some package that attempts to capture the environment body verbatim)

  If that's the case, consider trying out [my package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/prettytok). (the code is a mess right now, but well it works, and there are packages with worse source code out there)

Comment: And see also [compiling - How to trace LaTeX errors efficiently? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125399/how-to-trace-latex-errors-efficiently) .

Comment: In case `\myvariable` is defined to yield s.th. nice at the time of carrying out  `\typeout{\notexpandable{red}}`, `\typeout{\notexpandable{red}}` will not really crash but you need to look closely at the terminal output, not just skimming for error-messages/warnings...